# monitor and calculate asp.net website performance

Tags: c#, performance, httphandler

I need to monitor as asp.net website's performance: request time and page load time.

In order to measure request time and load time of page, 
I can create a http handler class and measure time between the `BeginProcessRequest` and `EndProcessRequest` functions, but I need also to measure the page load time (in case that server is fast, but network is slow).

Is there a way to make the measurements so in the same record to have both the server time and the client load time?

Comment: Have you tried to take a look a [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) for instance?

Comment: @kayess this sounds good, but the client don't want us to use third party libraries, only the code we write from scratch. But otherwise, this is a good solution

Comment: Are you aware that your clients needs nothing to install? You just add a NuGet package to your MVC project and that's it.

Comment: I know, but the client does not want to use these tools (except EF and MVC from nuget, it's a financial software)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following: [mvc-mini-profiler](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) .

You can also try the following VS tool: [Visual Studio Web performance testing tool](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/901/web-performance-test-using-visual-studio-part-i).

Comment: Hi, the page runs ok when I run it from visual studio. It runs slow when it is on the production environment. Our page is a mix between asp.net webforms and mvc, so I need a solution to cover both types of pages.

Comment: Did you try to use production application monitoring tools for .NET like for example [newrelic (APM)](http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring)?

Comment: hi, this is not free. I was looking for some code to get these measurements

Answer (score 0):

Why not enable [`Tracing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) at page level like below which will show you the page load time and even time taken by each controls on the page to load. You can as well consider using [`Fiddler`](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) tool.

```
 <%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

Comment: Hi, we don't have acces to the production environment, so we can't install stuff there